# fetch mode eager does not work

Tags: hibernate, grails

I defined:

```
static hasMany = [bankverbindung:Bankverbindung]

static fetchMode = [bankverbindung:'eager']
```

in a domain Class Partner, to avoid:

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.strotmann.immos.Partner.bankverbindung

but hibernate still seems to try lazy fetching and gives the obove error message.

what else can I try ?

peter
Dortmund Germany

Comment: Although `static fetchMode = [bankverbindung:'eager']` should work, you can also fetch collection eagerly by seting `bankverbindung lazy: false` in mapping closure.

Comment: what is a mapping closure, where to code it ?

Comment: It will be helpful if you put your domain model here, otherwise I have provided an example from grails doc.

Comment: sorry found the closure and coded it there, now it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Example from [Doc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#fetching)

```
class Airport {
String name
static hasMany = [flights: Flight]
static mapping = {
    flights lazy: false
  }
}
```